# Can I search within tags?

Tags: support, tagging, search

Is there an option to search within tags? If I am looking for recommendations on texts for, say algebra, and given the nature of the question I am pretty sure it exists. Is there a way I can search "algebra" within the self-learning and reference-request tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can scope the query by specifying the tag within `[]`

So the query: http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=[reference-request]+%22algebra%22

Note that, since algebra itself is a tag, you need to enclose it in quotes.